# Wrong EndDate on Sony's Calendar

Tags: java, android, date

I have an application which loads calendar events from Sqllite. The problem is when I send allday event to Sony's default calendar it moves enddate to one day back, while in other calendar apps it works as expected. How to make it universal for all calendars?

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setType("vnd.android.cursor.item/event");
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.TITLE, title);
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_BEGIN_TIME, startDate);
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.EXTRA_EVENT_END_TIME, endDate);
    intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.ALL_DAY, allDay); // periodicity
    if(allDay == true)
    {
        TimeZone tz = TimeZone.getDefault();
        String f = tz.getID();
        intent.putExtra(CalendarContract.Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, f);
    }
```

Result in Sony Calendar:

[image: Result in Sony Calendar]

Result in Other Calendars(example: Google):

[image: Result in Other Calendars]

String of allday event that I am clicking: 1560988800 it equals to 20/06/2019

Comment: It's probably a time zone issue. What are your long values? Which time zone are you in?

Comment: @OleV.V. Long values are date in milliseconds, timezone is UTC

Comment: If you posted the numbers, we could check in which time zones they agree with 19 June and in which with 20 June.

Comment: It's a poor idea to store your datetimes as seconds or milliseconds in your database. Strings in ISO 8601 format would have bern better. Since you have, you may search for an online Unix time converter and use it to check whether your stored times agree with the expected.

Comment: @OleV.V. Updated the question. You can find the numbers after screenshots.

Comment: 1560988800 seconds since the epoch is GMT: Thursday 20. June 2019 00:00:00, so if interpreted in UTC you should be fine. Apparently your calendar on Sony interprets in a time zone that is behind UTC, for example some time zone in the Americas. How to persuade it to use UTC I don’t know. Also, if this is both the start and end time, it’s pretty strange that it is interpreted differently as start and end time.

Comment: @OleV.V. Sony calendar uses GMT. I am sending in GMT, and startDate and endDate should be equal. But don't know why sony interprets it differently.

Comment: @OleV.V. Sony calendar gives error " Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.android.calendar/com.android.calendar.editevent.EditEventActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: allDay is true but sec, min, hour are not 0"

Comment: The way you describe it, it sounds like a bug in the Sony calendar. Usually when something looks like a bug in a standard library, it isn’t, though. So it would be interesting if others could reproduce it. I don’t have the setup to try it out myself, unfortunately.